# Google Drive REST API Get file returns 404 with scope "drive.file" only

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using google drive REST API V3 to access the file. The basic api url is:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileid

And the header contains key: Authorization with Bearer access token obtained from oauth.

However, if you create an normal google doc, this works. the response is:

```
{
"id": "1v3V0BWcWtYu_K9OLm1rffHA3vj5Bz8SY-0-JpU7CiEc",
"name": "test",
"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
"parents": [
    "0AP75Wn-e9WDqUk9PVA"
]
}
```

But if I created a google doc from **google template**, this returns 404. see below:

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "notFound",
            "message": "File not found: 14gHUCFTrwHaoZ88Kr0Qnn8OsUdzcU037GK7v-JI9L1I.",
            "locationType": "parameter",
            "location": "fileId"
        }
    ],
    "code": 404,
    "message": "File not found: 14gHUCFTrwHaoZ88Kr0Qnn8OsUdzcU037GK7v-JI9L1I."
}
}
```

Comment: The wired thing is if I use my addon "Open With --...." to open it once from Google Drive, now this document became accessible from the api.

Comment: That's the point of the `drive.file` scope... from the API, you can only access files that have been created or `open with...`'d an application on the same Google Cloud Project. Also, you don't show the code you're using that generates that error - consider showing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I requested more permissions, the problem solved. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

2021 answer here, in my case the issue (404 for some files) existed because the **Google project number I was using was wrong**.

And to make it harder, some accounts did work perfectly, and some did not using just this scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

As it is indicated in the google docs of the picker:

```
// Replace with your own project number from console.developers.google.com.
// See "Project number" under "IAM & Admin" > "Settings"
const appId = "1234567890";
```

After the project number was fixed, everything started working flawlessly (No need for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope as its a free-for-all scope that gives permissions for everything).

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me from pulling out the rest of my hair.

Comment: After pulling my hair out for a while I was skeptical but yes this appears to have fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit test and found that the "drive.file" scope actually has some problem with getting file metadata/content. From the documentation, the "drive.file" allow the app to access the file that created by this app, or user explicitly open the file with this app, from from drive or from google doc. When I testing this, actually this doesn't work as expect. I upload a few files, one of the files can be accessed by my app, but the others not. I remembered when I publish my app, the google drive team reviewed my app and rejected a few times with the scope, finially the app passed review with "drive.file" scope only.

Did anyone encounter same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Filling this in here for posterity: when using the drive.file permission with a file picker, the url/token you receive will only work if the picker was hosted on the same domain as is configured in the Google Developer Console Drive SDK configuration page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/drive_sdk).

If you are hosting it on any other domain, you'll get a 404 if you try and use the URL to directly download the file: you'll need to use drive.readonly or drive permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this is not the case. I created a google doc using the resume template. I obtained the fileID and run it against [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get). I got a 200 response:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1y1h2vHYwrb57O-ein7VhqMwwJKtr4pP4N4bBow7-vus",
 "name": "resumeTemplate",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
}
```

BTW, the URI requst for `files.get` is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
```

not

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes, I was using the correct api, with fileId. I'm not sure how this comes. But that happened to me. Also not just my account, I tested with my company's account, that also happened to me. I'm using postman to test this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was about setting `Drive.files().get(googleId).setSupportsAllDrives(true)` to gain access to files on shared drives.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says `drive.file` scope is used to view and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app.

I also encouraged 404 Error and I finally found the solution, In my case, I used Google Drive Picker in the front-end for selecting files, and then I send the file-ids to the backend for downloading them and I had the same `404 File not found` Error on the backend when I try to download files.

I see the error because I did not set appId in my picker API.
so when I try to instantiate googlePicker I set the app key and then everything is fixed.

```
// Replace with your own project number from console.developers.google.com.
// See "Project number" under "IAM & Admin" > "Settings"
var appId = "1234567890";

var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            ...
            .setAppId(appId)
            ...
            .build();
```

Now both backend and front-end use the same application in google and when the user selects a file from picker API it is available in all applications.

More info: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/